# Resolve variant of item shows NaN in Sitecore Profiler, how I can resolve this?

Tags: sitecore-client

When I use Sitecore debug mode it shows "Resolve variant of item" with 392,830 physical reads and with NaN% value too. How I can resolve it, I think it slows the page load, I am using Sitecore 8.0(rev. 150427).

Check the screenshot below :

[image]

Answer (score 0):

At least, there's a 7.1 related article on the Knowledge Base: https://kb.sitecore.net/articles/080849

Not sure if it works with 8.0.

Comment: I saw this article, sadly it's not applicable on 8.0